# Bunrndown for Task remaining as Task get closed during Iteration TFS 2013

Tags: backlog, burndowncharts

I have a request from the Project Management team if there is a way to have a brundown for Tasks remaining during an iteration. They would like to have this on the team home page of TFS web access and/or in the Backlog page right where we have burndown for remaining hours. Thank you..

Is that doable and how?

Comment: You mean a burndown for the number of tasks? Then the answer is no, if you were prepared to stop burning down hours I have an option. You might be able to make a custom SSRS report for this, but that won't be in the web access.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to create a query to filter the tasks, then create a chart for this query and pin the chart to homepage. For example:

[image]

[image]